# How to set Recyclerview adapter onCallBack

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-play-billing

On my activity's onCreate(), I initialized the recyclerview

```
private RecyclerView listView;

private Subscription subscription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listView = findViewById(R.id.subscription_list);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);

    listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    getPurchases(); //runs a service and sets subscription value and calls back onSkuDetails

}


@Override
public void onSkuDetails(List<SkuDetails> skuDetails) {

    ListCardAdapter listCardAdapter = new ListCardAdapter(getApplicationContext(), subscription, skuDetails);

    ListCardAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //this will return RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    listView.setAdapter(listCardAdapter);

    removeProgressDialog();

}
```

I tried setting layoutManager inside onSkuDetails but it stops going to next line after setLayoutManager , I did some research and the results says:

1. it's because of the setting of layoutManager.
2. Must set the adapter onCreate() or main thread.

PS: I updated google play billing library to latest(4.0) that have changes on my classes related to this activity, google play billing is working.

Comment: set the adapter after setting layout manger. you can update your adapter later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out that you just need to update adapter properties/data instead of setting the adapter again then just call notifyDataSetChanged()

```
private ListCardAdapter listCardAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listView = findViewById(R.id.subscription_list);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);

    listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listCardAdapter= new ListCardAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    listCardAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    listCardAdapter.setAdapter(subscriptionListCardAdapter);

    getPurchases();

}

@Override
public void onSkuDetails(List<SkuDetails> skuDetails) {

    removeProgressDialog();

    listCardAdapter.setData(subscription, skuDetails);

}

//ListCardAdapter 
public void setData(Subscription subscription, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

    this.subscription = subscription;

    this.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you call the `getPurchases()` after the view is created in onStart of Activity or onViewCreated in Fragment. This is to avoid cases where response is returned before the view creation.

Next I am assuming your `ListView.setAdapter(listCardAdapter);` is a typo and you meant it to be `listView`. After setting the adapter, you should call `listCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for the `recyclerView` to know the data has changed.

Best approach is to set the adapter **without** constructor params initially and later add the data via a method in the adapter which accepts subscription and sku details as the parameters.

Also another major thing to highlight, you will never get the item click because you are setting `onClickListener` on the adapter. You should pass an interface reference which gets called in `onBindViewHolder` method and `onClickListener` should be triggering callback on that listener reference.

Check this answer for the code snippet of the same. This is not part of question so it will be treated as a separate question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471410/4491971